# base method is not fired in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following base controller

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
   protected override void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   {

          base.Execute(requestContext);
   }
}
```

Implementation is

```
  public class HomeController : BaseController { }
```

we upgraded from mvc3 to mvc5 , in mvc5 this method is not getting called what needs to be done here ?

Comment: ur control is not coming to basecontroller or something else?

Comment: its hitting the baseController but not hitting the execute methood

Comment: Can you show us your implementation?

Comment: added the implementation, every controller in application implements the basecontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your after but here's a few questions.  Are your normal controllers inheriting your BaseController?

```
public class MyController : BaseController
```

I don't see what this line is meant to do....

```
var global = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["global"] == null ? true : false;
```

You set the value then don't do anything with it.  Are you meaning to store this value in the base controller so that you can access it from all your other controllers?

And surely if global is missing from the querystring then it should be false and not true.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
   public bool isGlobal { get; private set; }

   protected override void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   {
      this.isGlobal = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["global"] == null ? false : true;
      base.Execute(requestContext);
   }
}
```

Comment: "Surely" you don't know the business rules surrounding the `global` flag.

Comment: I added that because, sometime this app gets called from another windows application that is for internal use, the question this execute method is not fired at any time, whats the reason

Answer (score 2):

The title of this question led me here, but it's not really the same problem I was experiencing (i.e. the overridden `Execute` method in a base controller class not being called in an MVC 4/5 web site).

If that is the problem you are having too, this is the solution I found. It appears the way in which these methods are called has changed with the introduction of Async support. Instead of overriding the `Execute` method you should override the `OnActionExecuted` method instead.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
}
```